# Javascript Regex Check if string has word that does not belong

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string with times (formatted HH:MM) each on a new line. I want to create a JS function to check if there is any times that does not belong. It should simply return `true` or `false`.

Example correct string: `var s = "5:45\n07:00\n13:00\n17:00";`

> 5:45
>   07:00
>   13:00
>   17:00

Example incorrect string: `var s = "5:45\n07:00\n55:00\n17:00";`

> 5:45
>   07:00
>   55:00  // incorrect date here, should return false
>   17:00

My regex experience is little to none. Playing around on [Scriptular](http://scriptular.com/) I created this expression to detect times that do match:
`/^[0-2]?[0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]$/m`. This however is not sufficient.

So, how can I get this to work with a string `s` as indicated above?

```
function checkIfStringConforms(s)
{
  var all_good = [some magic with regex here]
  return all_good;
}
```

PS: I have Googled around and checked answers on SO. My regex skill is... eh.

Comment: So is `5:45` correct? H:MM is ok?

Comment: `^(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0123]):[0-5][0-9]$`

Comment: @AlexK. Yes it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is OK, but it would also match `29:00`, so it needs some improvement. Then, it's always a bit more difficult to find non-matches than it is to find matches. You could try and remove all matches from the string and then see if it's empty (except for whitespace):

```
result = s.replace(/^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/mg, "");
```

If `result` is empty after that, there were no illegal times in your string.

Comment: Thanks for also correcting my regex for checking that it is a legitimate time.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without the use of any regex. Just split on new-line and see if every date matches your format. For that we could use `Array.every`

```
function checkIfStringConforms(s) {
    return s.split("\n").every(function(str){
        var arr = str.split(":");
        return (arr[0] < 24 && arr[0] > -1) && arr[1] < (60 && arr[1] > -1)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`/(((2[^0-3]|[3-9].):..)|(..?:[^0-5].))(\n|$)/`

Regexp returns `true` if your `s` var has at least one invalid time. Please, check it carefully before use – your question is quite broad and restrictions are not fully defined. Regex assumes that you have something like x:xx or xx:xx in each line (x is a digit) – I’m not sure this assumption covers all your data.